# "Verifying transaction: failed" in Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-3.7

I am tried to do setup tensorflow in anaconda.
I install Anaconda3-2019.03 which support pyhton3x. Now I learnt a lot and I could know that tensorflow doesn't works in Python 3.7.0 . That's why I update the Python version into Python 3.6.0 so that I can use tensorflow and I can install may be all packages but after all packages installation,
I run a command in anaconda promots,

```
conda install python=3.6.0
```

but it shown an error and that is,

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: failed
```

[image: Error screenshots]

**Note:** How can i solve this issue?
Please help me. Advanced thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu could create a new environment inside of conda dedicated for 3.6 with:
`conda create --name py36 python=3.6`
But then you also have to install tensorflow in there as well.
But Tensorflow works with Python 3.7.

Comment: brother !   After "conda create --name py36 python=3.6" and "conda activate py36" command should i  install tensorflow  using "pip install tensorflow" command???

Comment: Yes, it will show you anyways if its already installed, if you run that command.

Comment: Ok brother,  i am installing tensorflow.